# How to create a radio button with on and off function to display an image?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a radio group with two button on and off in Android Studio. I already created the radio group with two button. I want when the user clicks on an picture will appear beneath them and if the user clicks off the picture will disappear. Thank you.
Here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.android.testapp;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import static android.view.View.GONE; 
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;
import static com.example.android.testapp.R.id.imageView;
import static com.example.android.testapp.R.id.radioButton;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if(rb.ischecked()){ image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:checked="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="SetImage"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Off"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:checked="false" />

</RadioGroup>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
     />
```

Comment: Show related part of code

Comment: @Adu : see my answer probably help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for `RadioGroup` to change image visibility according to `RadioButton` click.

**1.** Add id to `RadioGroup` in xml :

```
android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
```

**2.** Add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to RadioGroup in `onCreate` method after `setContentView` :

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
// find which radio button is selected
  if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton) {
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);           
  } else if(checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);              
  }  
}});
```

Comment: doesn't work too. it says "setVisibility" cannot resolve method. I did exactly what you told me.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton2) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: @AbuMohanad: why you removed `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);` line?

Comment: @AbuMohanad: move add `ImageView image;`  line before `@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`  line and use `image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);` before `RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);` line

Comment: well done my friend. I named Onclick "SetImage" that made all that miss with my program. I wish I would be smart like you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have 2 radio buttons if you only want a on/off state. One is enough and when it will be checked then you can make your picture appear and if it's unchecked, you can make it disappear. How to do this, in your onCreate method, you can write:

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

if(rb.isChecked()){
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: @Icw_gg thank you for the help but it doesn't work with me. Please see my code above.